# How to save "albums" in Swift & SwiftUI (Music App)

Tags: ios, swift

INTRO
I am new to swift and swiftui. I have been creating projects to increase my skills in ios development and hopefully land a job in ios development.

**PROBLEM**

My current project is a Music App and it basically gets the user to download an mp3 file and add it  to the app using FileManager. The problem now is storing of albums and the creation of one.

I could not wrap my head around how to save such data.

**My first solution is:**

- to create a folder when the user creates an album and push the file there (basically copying and pasting the same file).

the problem with that is the storage space

**My second solution (which is not yet confirmed) is**

- to create a text or any data file that could give out the list of songs in a album which would be 100% better than the first solution.

P.S.
This is just a side project so a streaming/online database is not a viable solution for me as I don't have any money for that. (and yes even free tiers since I don't have any credit cards)

I am not sure yet what I will do with it.

Comment: Look at Core Data. You could create an entity called `Track` with properties like name and artist and the name of the file that is stored in the file system. You can then make an entity called `Album` that has a to-many relationship to `Track`. The `Track` would also have a to-many relationship with `Album`. That way a track can be in many albums but you only have a single instance of the actual file.